# Function to make a "card" using array of structures

Tags: c, arrays, string, struct

I have a function here where I am making a deck of cards. At the end I have it print what is in each cards struct but it prints weird characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DECK 52
#define RANK 8
#define SUIT 15



/* SpEcIaL VaRiAbLeS */
struct card{

    char rank[RANK];
    char suite[SUIT];


} card;

enum suites{ 
SPADES, DIAMONDS, CLUBS, HEARTS};

/* ***************************Prototypes ************************/

void deck_fill( struct card blank_deck[] );
```

This is the driver function.

```
int main( void )
{
    struct card deck[DECK];

    deck_fill( deck);

    printf( "The card is %s of %s", deck[0].suite, deck[0].rank);



    return 0;
}
```

this is the function in question. hopefully at the end of this my deck array is filled with "cards".

```
 /* Definitions */
 void deck_fill( struct card blank_deck[] )
 {
    struct card *deck_change = &blank_deck;
    int i, k, j;



    while (k < 4)
    {
        k = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 13; i++)
        {
            switch(k)
            {
                case (0): 
                    memcpy(deck_change[i].suite, "SPADES", 6);
                    break;

                case (1):           
                    memcpy(deck_change[i+13].suite, "DIAMONDS", 8);
                    break;

                case (2):
                    memcpy(deck_change[i + 26].suite, "CLUBS", 5);
                    break;

                case (3): 
                    memcpy(deck_change[i + 39].suite, "HEARTS", 6);
                    break;
            }
        }

        k++;

    }

    deck_change[DECK] = 0;
}
```

When ran it prints "The card is  of R1S or (somethingweird)".
why?

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: remove `&` in this line: `struct card *deck_change = &blank_deck;`

Comment: Read this please: [mcve].

Comment: `memcpy(deck_change[i].suite, "SPADES", 6);` --> `memcpy(deck_change[i].suite, "SPADES", 7);`. Also `k = 0;` move to before while-loop.

Comment: Delete `deck_change[DECK] = 0;`

Comment: `deck[0].rank` is uninitialized.

Comment: it should be noted that a `enum` statement produces integers, not characters

Comment: this code: `struct card
{
    char rank[RANK];
    char suite[SUIT];
} card;` is creating an instance of 'struct card' that has the name 'card.  However, that instance is not being used in the posted code.  suggest removing the characters 'card' between the closing brace and the final semicolon

Comment: the problem is caused by the code in the body of the `deck_fill()` function, starting with this line: `struct card *deck_change = &blank_deck;` which should NOT have the `address of` operator applied to the passed in variable `blank)deck`.

Comment: variables on the stack are not initialized by the application load process. so this line: `while (k < 4)`  probably fails, then none of the `while()` loop is executed.  However, since testing the contents of an uninitialized variable results in undefined behavior anything could be happening.  Suggest this line: `int i, k, j;`  be changed to three lines: `int i; int k=0;`  and remove the reference to `j` since that variable is not used

Comment: suggest removing this line: `k++;` and modifying these lines: `while (k < 4)
    {
        k = 0;`   to: `for( int k=0; k<4; k++ ) {`

Comment: the posted code fails to set the field `char rank[RANK];` to a known value

Comment: in C, an index into an array starts at 0 and continues to number of entries in the array -1.   So this line: `deck_change[DECK] = 0;` is writing beyond the end of the array.  This results in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers. 'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 0, 1, 2, 3, 13.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using  `#define` statements or an `enum` statement to  give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those names throughout the code.  Note: for the values 0, 1 ,2 ,3 there is already the `enum suites`

Answer (score 0):

try to use this deck_fill() function. Don't forget to assing rank

```
void deck_fill(struct card blank_deck[])
 {
    struct card *deck_change = blank_deck;
    int i, j;
    int k = 0;
    char index[2];
    char c;

    while (k < 4)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 13; i++)
        {
            switch(k)
            {
                case (0): 
                    strncpy(deck_change[i].suite, "SPADES", 6);
                    deck_change[i].rank = i;
                    break;

                case (1):           
                    strncpy(deck_change[i+13].suite, "DIAMONDS", 8);
                    deck_change[i+13].rank = i;
                    break;

                case (2):
                    strncpy(deck_change[i+26].suite, "CLUBS", 5);
                    deck_change[i+26].rank = i;
                    break;

                case (3): 
                    strncpy(deck_change[i+39].suite, "HEARTS", 6);
                    deck_change[i+39].rank = i;
                    break;
            }
        }
        k++;
    }
    //deck_change[DECK] = 0;
}
```

and change struct wtih this

```
struct card{
    int rank;
    char suite[SUIT];
} card;
```

Comment: If i did it this way how would i do Ace, Jack etc, thats why I used char array, I not doing any math with the numbers